# Restrict C# code from ASP.NET framework features

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, security

Is it possible to restrict code access for certain .NET functionality/classes?

For example, I have plugin modules for my MVC CMS. I wouldn't want 3rd party modules able to use the File class directly. I would want to wrap it up in an API so that the module can only access files in it's own designated 'root' folder (sandbox). Otherwise, the module would have file access to the entire server, including the CMS system files.

Is there a way to restrict certain namespaces from using particular features of the framework? Or is there a different approach that I should take?

**To give you an overview:**

The CMS namespace is `MyCms`

All modules take the namespace `MyCms.Module.xxxxx`

Modules are just standard MVC structures that are brought into the name main MVC namespace, and routes are automatically set up to route requests to the module controllers.

Therefore the modules have default access to the ASP.NET framework. I want to be able to restrict MyCms.Module.xxxxx namespaces from being able to do certain things, if that is possible.

Have I taken the wrong approach here? I'm not keen to change the infrastructure to be honest, but may be forced to if I can't properly secure the main CMS infrastructure from naughty modules.

Comment: Whats wrong with scoping methods, eg: Private, Internal, or making methods not overrable?

Comment: You can either load the code for the 3rd party assembly into a separate AppDomain (allows unloading, but is more work), which can be configured to have a tailored set of permissions available. Use System.AddIn for this. Alternatively, you can drop certain permissions before calling into the 3rd party code. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2009/06/12/clr-v4-security-policy-roundup.aspx for a good starting point on CAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, the .net/ the common language runtime supports a wide set of privilege restrictions and customizations you can put in for what code can do what.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbk2s3fa%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) is an overview of how it worked prior to .net 4

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/.aspx

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233103.aspx) is how it works now

This stuff is a little complicated and my work with it was limited to bipassing some of it for test cases I had to  write, but  it was written to provide precisely the functionality you seek.

Comment: Thanks, I started working with CAS yesterday. My initial solution would be to give the application the lowest level of security, then add in fullTrustAssembly elements for those assemblies that are considered safe (i.e. system.web.mvc and the core CMS assembly). Then I'll create an API for modules to access the file system using a SecuritySafeCritical attribute on each API method. What are your thoughts on this approach? I haven't coded it yet so not sure if it will even work. Can you offer any suggestions or inform me of any obstacles you had to overcome? Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going give your 3rd party source code or Just a compiled API dll?
if it's later, then a setting up a interface and only exposing methods you want your 3rd party  to use, sounds like a answer to me.
of course, it is also heavily relied on the architect of your codebase.

or simply providing your 3rd party a specified document would do the trick as well

Comment: I've updated my question with an overview of my setup. in short the modules have access to source code.